# Find triple of opposite values in list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of triples of either 0 or 1. I would like to a pythonic way  to create tuples of opposites such that:

`l = [(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1),(0, 1, 1),(0, 0, 1)]`

becomes:

`new_l = [((0, 1, 1),(1, 0, 0)), ((1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), ((1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)), ((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1))]`

Comment: So what should happen if there is no negated version of a tuple in the list?

Comment: Also, have you made any attempt yourself yet?

Comment: In my implementation I know that there is always a negated version. Maybe for the more general case just return "error".

Comment: I was just going to create all negated versions and then somehow get the unique tuples and form a list. I am not a "pythonista" so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Does order matter? Or can the pairs be returned in any order?

Comment: The pairs can be returned in any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
new_l = [tuple(x) for x in set(frozenset([tup, tuple(int(not t) for t in tup)]) for tup in l) if not x-set(l)]
```

which gets each value and creates its opposite by doing `tuple(int(not t) for t in tup)`. Its stores each pair as a frozen set and then takes the `set` of all of these which removes duplicates.  Then, it converts this set of sets back into a list of tuples but only keeps the pairs where both values appear in the original list `l` by checking if the difference of the set `x` and the set of the original list `l` is the empty set.

```
print(new_l)
[((0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)), ((1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)), ((1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), ((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1))]
```

**EDIT**

with Martijn Pieters suggestions (see comments):

```
setl = set(l) 
new_l = [tuple(x) for x in set(frozenset([tup, tuple(1-t for t in tup)]) for tup in l) if x.issubset(setl)]
```

Comment: This is basically the same approach as mine, albeit doing a bit more work and less readable.

Comment: Also, the `not x - set(l)` has to create a *two new sets* each iteration. I'd use `x.issubset(l)` to avoid this busy-work. The latter is probably more efficient as `setl = set(l)` (outside the loop) and `x.issubset(l)` (inside the loop).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're absolutely right. Using `isdisjoint` is much more readable.  So is your use of `tuple(1-v for v in t)` to be honest.  I'll add an edit to this with your suggestions.

Comment: `isdisjoint()` is actually wrong, you want to make sure *both* tuples in a pair are in `l`, so you need `issubset()`. I already corrected for this.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, if you are absolutely certain that every tuple has a corresponding opposite in `l` you can do `list(zip(sorted(l), sorted(l,reverse=True)))` .

Comment: Way to kill the efficiency though.

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely not efficient. Just another way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a canonical version of the tuple; either the one that starts with `0` or the opposite one. Use the canonical as the key in a dictionary to build a list of all tuples that share that canonical value; the values of the dictionary become your pairs:

```
def canonical(t):
    return t if t[0] == 0 else tuple(1 - v for v in t)

def pair_values(l):
    paired = {}
    for t in l:
        paired.setdefault(canonical(t), []).append(t)
    if any(len(v) != 2 for v in paired.values()):
        raise ValueError("Not all tuples could be paired up")
    return [tuple(p) for p in paired.values()]
```

If you are 100% certain the tuples can always be paired up, I'd just drop the `any()` test altogether.

The above produces the output in O(N) time; you only need to iterate over the input a constant number of times (1.5 or 2 times N, depending on wether or not you want to test for proper pairs first).

Demo:

```
>>> # a tuple and its inversion both always produce the same canonical
... 
>>> canonical((1, 1, 0))
(0, 0, 1)
>>> canonical((0, 0, 1))
(0, 0, 1)
>>> l = [(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1),(0, 1, 1),(0, 0, 1)]
>>> pair_values(l)
[((1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), ((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1)), ((1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)), ((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1))]
```